# Geoserver java.IOExceptionInvalid value for parameter (possible utf-8 issue)

Tags: geoserver, sql-view, utf-8

i m trying to query a view using parameters in Greek

```
SELECT [OBJECTID]
  ,[Shape]
  ,[SubStore]
  ,[StoreCode]
  ,[subStore] 
 FROM [****].[dbo].[GSRV_POLYGONS]
 where [StoreCode]>='%StoreCodemin%'
 and [StoreCode]<='%StoreCodemax%'
 and [subStore]>='%substoremin%'
 and [subStore]<='%substoremax%'
```

and i am getting the following error

code="internalError"Rendering process failed. Layers:GSRV_POLYGONS java.IOExceptionInvalid value for parameter StoreCodemin.

StoreCode is nvarchar and subStore is integer.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Invalid value for parameter StoreCodemin" means that the regular expression validating the parameter did not consider the input value valid.

Indeed the regular expressions are not compiled with Unicode support, so it might be a UTF-8 issue. If that's the case, you could:

- Set up a regular expression that would match Unicode chars
- Change the GeoTools code that builds the regular expressions, so that Unicode chars are supported by default, write a test to go with it, and issue a PR

Both avenues are explained in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10894122/java-regex-for-support-unicode).
You can also [open a bug report](https://osgeo-org.atlassian.net/projects/GEOS/summary), and/or sponsor some [core developer](https://geoserver.org/support/) to perform a fix for you.

Comment: Thank you i removed regex validation and it works

Comment: That is really dangerous though, you're open to a SQL injection attack now.